# Decrypt and store blob items from Azure container

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I want to decrypt blob items stored in a container and then I want to store that blob item to my local machine.

Below is my code to decrypt the blob

```
X509Store certStore = new X509Store();
string password = string.Empty;
X509Certificate2 certificate = 
FindCertificateByThumbprint
(@ConfigProvider.DecryptionCertificateFingerprint);
string containerName = @ConfigProvider.ContainerName;
CloudBlobContainer CsvContainer = GetAzureContainer(containerName);
var provider = new AsymmetricBlobCryptoProvider(certificate);
var decryptedMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();

foreach (IListBlobItem item in CsvContainer.ListBlobs(null, false))
{
    if (item.GetType() == typeof(CloudBlockBlob))
    {
        CloudBlockBlob blobItem = (CloudBlockBlob)item;
        CloudBlockBlob Csvblob = 
        CsvContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(blobItem.Name);
        Csvblob.DownloadToStreamEncrypted(provider, 
        decryptedMemoryStream);
    }
}
```

How can I download these decrypted blobs on my local machine?

Comment: What is the problem you're running into? Is your question about saving the `decryptedMemoryStream` to a file on your local machine?

Comment: Yes. I want to store it on a local drive.

Comment: You've managed to get here, but you can't figure out how to open a file stream and copy your decrypted memory stream to it? That's like two lines of code.

Comment: Thank you Will for giving me hints. 
If you were my boss then I can solve many problems :)

Comment: using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(@"<your path>" + blobItem.Name, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
                    {
                        decryptedMemoryStream.WriteTo(fileStream);
                    }